# PHP and Javascript Input Field Validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation, lamp

i got a LAMP enviornment.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
<form method="post" name="" id="" onsubmit="javascriptValidateFormUserInputs()">
...
</form>
```

As the name already says the javascriptValidateFormUserInputs(), validates inputs done by the user. If they are ok true is returned otherwise false.

If i manipulate the html clientside to `onsubmit="true"` no validation is done and the users invalid data is sent to the database.

I want to prevent that of course.

What to do ?

Thanks

Comment: you have to do validation by php scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using php, then server-side validation is always better as client side validation can be tampered with.

So you just need to check if `$_POST("variable")` has been validated otherwise return an error.

You may follow this example - [PHP Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)

Comment: So i will have to change my javascript validation to php scripts ?

Comment: you can keep your javascript validation but on top of that add the php validation as well.

Comment: So i need to set a php variable when javascriptValidation returns true ?

Sorry its my first Website

Comment: I have added an example you can follow in my answer. You may use any other example - there are quite a few out there.

Answer (score 1):

You should never rely on client-side validation: user can disable javascript or even perform any HTTP request to your server (outside the browser).

You need to have server-side validation in any case.

Client-side validation should only be seen as a user-friendly improvement to your base server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never trust the client side validation through (Javascript or jquery) both of them can be easily bypassed just by turning off the Javascript in a browser.
2. Always, always, always do and use server side validation ( yes this can add little bit load on server but still you have to use it)